# Android Видеозапись Установка длительности записи

Tags: android, камера

Устанавливаю

```
mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000);
```

А видеозапись длится всего 10 секунд.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что использовал свой таймер на длительность видео. Забыл про него.